# Botão "OK" na mensagem de alerta -

Tags: swift, xcode

Alguém pode me ajudar

Qual a forma correta no Swift 2? pede para remover o "Let okAction", mas ai eu perco a referência e o alerta fica sem botão.

> let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

Código completo para facilitar:

```
    @IBAction func singUpButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = userEmailAddressTextField.text
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
    let userPasswordRepeat = userPasswordRepeatTextField.text
    let userFirstName = userFirstNameTextField.text
    let userLastName = userLastNameTextField.text


    if( userPassword != userPasswordRepeat) {

        displayAlertMessage("Passwords do not match")
        return
    }

    if(userEmail!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty || userFirstName!.isEmpty || userLastName!.isEmpty )
    {
        displayAlertMessage("Passwords do not match")
        return
    }


}

func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu `UIAlertAction` está ok. Como não postou de fato o erro apresentado, eu acredito que é warning de compilação avisando que você não está utilizando o action criado, uma vez não usado, pode ser removido.

O que falta você fazer é adicionar sua `action` ao `alert`:

```
func displayAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

    myAlert.addAction(okAction)

    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```